# Send parameters to controller when clicking a button - Java Play

Tags: java, html, api, playframework

I'm trying to send parameters when clicking on a button to a function. However, I get the following error:

> app/views/index.scala.html:44:84: not found: value postid [error]

**index.scala.html:**

```
<section class="search-sec">
    <div class="container">
        <form action="window.location.href='@routes.AppController.retrieveByFields(postid, text_filter)';" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input type="text" id="postid" name = "postid" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter Post Id" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input type="text" id= "text_filter" name="text_filter" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Enter text to search">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
                            <input type="submit" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger wrn-btn">Search</button>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Routes**

```
GET     /comments/:id               controllers.AppController.retrieveByFields(id: Int, text: java.util.Optional[String])
```

**Controller function**

```
public Result retrieveByFields(int postid, java.util.Optional<String> text) throws IOException, ParseException
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your views file, it does not know what your `postid` is. Two things:

1. Have you defined your form values in your controller?
2. Have you passed them to your views?